# sqlalchemy func.min and where clause

Tags: sqlalchemy

i'm new of sqlalchemy,

i'm trying to write this select

```
select job_id, 
       machine_id,
       state_id, 
       min(begin_time) as begin_time 
from job 
where machine_id = 2 
  and state_id = 2
```

the first time i've tried to write this..

```
session.query(Job).filter(and_(Job.begin_time==session.query(func.min(Job.begin_time)),
             Job.state_id==2,Job.machine_id == 2)).all()
```

but return an empty list because it found another min begin_time row .

i've tried another way:

```
jobRecordSucces = session.query(Job).filter(Job.state_id==2,Job.machine_id == 2)

jobRecordSuccessivo = session.query(jobRecordSucces).filter(jobRecordSucces .begin_time==session.query(func.min(jobRecordSucces.begin_time)))
```

but the second query return me this error

```
InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - 
got '<sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query 
 object at 0x04491B10>'
```

thanks in advance :-)